# SimpleCursorAdapter with ImageView and TextView from SQLite

Tags: java, android

I want to do an Phonebook, "name" Save names, "sname" Save phone, "img" to store pictures, But, the name and telephone can be displayed,iamge is stored using BASE64,Picture how to deal with?

---

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu);
    tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    tv1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    Typeface face = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/aaq.otf");
    tv.setTypeface(face);
    edt1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);    
    lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);

    Toast a=Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Message Toast!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    a.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER , 0, 0);
    a.show();
    db = openOrCreateDatabase(DB_NAME,  Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
    try {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE hotlist");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }

    cur=db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+ TB_NAME, null); 
  adapter=new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, 
            R.layout.mylayout, cur, 
            FROM, 
            new int[] {R.id.textView11,R.id.textView22,R.id.imageView11}, 0);
    adapter.setViewBinder(new SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder() {
        public boolean setViewValue(View view, Cursor cursor, int columnIndex) {
          if (view.getId() == R.id.imageView11)
            {
            String cc=cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndexOrThrow("img"));
            byte[] aa=cc.getBytes();
            Bitmap bb=BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(aa, 0,aa.length);
              ((ImageView)view).setImageBitmap(bb);
                    return true;}

          return false;}
    });



}
```

---

11-01 22:17:50.051: E/AndroidRuntime(4766): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-01 22:17:50.051: E/AndroidRuntime(4766): Process: com.example.electronicard, PID: 4766
11-01 22:17:50.051: E/AndroidRuntime(4766): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.electronicard/com.example.electronicard.Menu}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column 'img' does not exist
11-01 22:17:50.051: E/AndroidRuntime(4766):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2596)
11-01 22:17:50.051: E/AndroidRuntime(4766):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2653)
11-01 22:17:50.051: E/AndroidRuntime(4766):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:156)
11-01 22:17:50.051: E/AndroidRuntime(4766):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1355)
11-01 22:17:50.051: E/AndroidRuntime(4766):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
11-01 22:17:50.051: E/AndroidRuntime(4766):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
11-01 22:17:50.051: E/AndroidRuntime(4766):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5883)
11-01 22:17:50.051: E/AndroidRuntime(4766):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-01 22:17:50.051: E/AndroidRuntime(4766):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
11-01 22:17:50.051: E/AndroidRuntime(4766):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:871)
11-01 22:17:50.051: E/AndroidRuntime(4766):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:687)
11-01 22:17:50.051: E/AndroidRuntime(4766):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-01 22:17:50.051: E/AndroidRuntime(4766): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column 'img' does not exist
11-01 22:17:50.051: E/AndroidRuntime(4766):     at android.database.AbstractCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(AbstractCursor.java:309)
11-01 22:17:50.051: E/AndroidRuntime(4766):     at android.support.v4.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter.findColumns(SimpleCursorAdapter.java:317)
11-01 22:17:50.051: E/AndroidRuntime(4766):     at android.support.v4.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter.(SimpleCursorAdapter.java:92)
11-01 22:17:50.051: E/AndroidRuntime(4766):     at com.example.electronicard.Menu.onCreate(Menu.java:59)
11-01 22:17:50.051: E/AndroidRuntime(4766):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5312)
11-01 22:17:50.051: E/AndroidRuntime(4766):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1111)
11-01 22:17:50.051: E/AndroidRuntime(4766):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2552)
11-01 22:17:50.051: E/AndroidRuntime(4766):     ... 11 more

Answer (score 0):

Your database stores image data BASE64 encoded, you have to decode it into the equivalent byte[] data before BitmapFactory can use it. BASE64 decoding is not the same as `cc.getBytes()` - that just gives you the byte values of the characters in the string.

```
byte[] aa = Base64.decode(cc, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

is the correct way (maybe with a different [flag](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Base64.html#URL_SAFE)).

I would not do that every time you access the image data, storing it as already decoded binary `BLOB` in the database (or if data is > 100kB as actual file on SD) is far more efficient with regards to space and speed. http://androidsurya.blogspot.de/2012/11/insert-and-retrieve-image-from-sqlite.html looks like a usable example.

Comment: but,You can provide simplecursoradapter setviewbind usage it,please

Comment: @KennyHuang if you just replace `byte[] aa=cc.getBytes();` with what I wrote above there, is it working then? Your code doesn't look wrong.

Comment: I try to replace, but still can not be

Comment: Recently busy, try again a little later so you give me the URL, Will the you write adapter around a friend?

Comment: @KennyHuang Can you explain what happen? Does it compile?

Comment: I want to do a similar program phonebook functions, program an open collapsed I do not know what went wrong.

Comment: That error is " column 'img' does not exist" in your database. It has either a different name or you have not added that column to the "create table" statement or you may have to reset the entire app data because old database versions are not removed when you install a new app version

Comment: I try to move in this direction! Thank you! @zapl

Comment: String createTable="CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TB_NAME +
             "(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + 
             "name VARCHAR, " +
             "sname VARCHAR" +
             "img VARCHAR)";
        db.execSQL(createTable);